# MySQl - SQL - Top 5 records per day

Tags: mysql, sql

With respect to the data set below, I'm trying to get the top 5 records per day on a MySQL database. It's a table of web page visits & my aim is to find out the 5 most visited pages.

I'm comfortable getting just the top 10 in a given date range, but, have not been able to manage to get a query going for the topic in question.

I did try the below

```
select 
    VISIT_DATE,
    group_concat(PAGE_ID order by NUM_VISITS desc separator ',') as pagehits
from 
    PAGEVISITS
where 
    VISIT_DATE >= '2015-07-01' and VISIT_DATE <= '2015-07-15'
group by
    VISIT_DATE
```

but I can't get `SUM(NUM_VISITS)` int here & I couldn't get `group by`VISIT_DATE` which makes it pretty useless. This apart, this is how far I've got

```
select 
    VISIT_DATE,
    PAGE_ID,
    SUM(NUM_VISITS) as pagehits
 from
   PAGEVISITS
 where 
   VISIT_DATE >= '2015-01-01' and VISIT_DATE <= '2015-03-15'
 group by
   VISIT_DATE,
   PAGE_ID
order by
    pagehits desc
limit 5;
```

which obviously is not top 5 per day. Also, there could be more than one page that can end up having the same number of page hits obviously & may also end up appearing as one of the top 5 which is why I tried using group concat to display all those PAGE IDs whose number of page hits is in the top 5 page hit count for that day.

I'm not a seasoned SQL coder. Could I please request assistance to get this working. If I've not sounded clear anywhere, please do let me know.

```
CREATE TABLE PAGEVISITS
    (`VISIT_DATE` date, `PAGE_ID` varchar(20),  `SERVER_NAME` varchar(50), `NUM_VISITS` int)
;

INSERT INTO PAGEVISITS
    (`VISIT_DATE`, `PAGE_ID`, `SERVER_NAME`, `NUM_VISITS`)
VALUES
('2015-01-01','2015A12123','A',10),
('2015-01-01','2015A12123','B',10),
('2015-01-01','2015A12124','A',30),
('2015-01-01','2015A12124','B',30),
('2015-01-01','2015A12125','A',40),
('2015-01-01','2015A12125','B',40),
('2015-01-01','2015A12126','A',1),
('2015-01-01','2015A12126','B',1),
('2015-01-01','2015A12127','A',0),
('2015-01-01','2015A12127','B',1),
('2015-01-01','2015A12128','A',40),
('2015-01-01','2015A12129','A',30),
('2015-01-01','2015A12134','A',45),
('2015-01-01','2015A12126','A',56),
('2015-01-01','2015A12167','A',23),
('2015-01-01','2015A12145','A',17),
('2015-01-01','2015A121289','A',12),
('2015-01-01','2015A121289','B',5),
('2015-01-02','2015A12123','A',3),
('2015-01-02','2015A12124','A',10),
('2015-01-02','2015A12125','A',70),
('2015-01-02','2015A12126','A',10),
('2015-01-02','2015A12127','A',100),
('2015-01-02','2015A12128','A',3),
('2015-01-02','2015A12128','B',2),
('2015-01-02','2015A12129','A',10),
('2015-01-02','2015A12134','A',5),
('2015-01-02','2015A12126','A',6),
('2015-01-02','2015A12167','A',3),
('2015-01-02','2015A12145','A',170),
('2015-01-02','2015A121289','A',34),
('2015-01-03','2015A12123','A',34),
('2015-01-03','2015A12124','A',14),
('2015-01-03','2015A12125','A',37),
('2015-01-03','2015A12126','A',23),
('2015-01-03','2015A12127','A',234),
('2015-01-03','2015A12128','A',47),
('2015-01-03','2015A12129','A',67),
('2015-01-03','2015A12134','A',89),
('2015-01-03','2015A12134','B',1),
('2015-01-03','2015A12126','A',97),
('2015-01-03','2015A12167','A',35),
('2015-01-03','2015A12145','A',0),
('2015-01-03','2015A121289','A',19), 
('2015-01-04','2015A12123','A',115),
('2015-01-04','2015A12124','A',149),
('2015-01-04','2015A12125','A',370),
('2015-01-04','2015A12126','A',34),
('2015-01-04','2015A12127','A',4),
('2015-01-04','2015A12128','A',70),
('2015-01-04','2015A12129','B',70),
('2015-01-04','2015A12134','A',70),
('2015-01-04','2015A12126','B',64),
('2015-01-04','2015A12167','A',33),
('2015-01-04','2015A12145','A',10);
```

**ANTICIPATED OUTPUT**

[image]
 Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1701f5/1)

Comment: Thank you Strawberry. The primary key is an auto increment dummy integer field. I've updated the expected result

Comment: Come on. You can do better than that. Also you appear to have a natural key on VISIT_DATE, PAGE_ID, SERVER_NAME,  rendering the surrogate AI id redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is going to be used daily, then you should consider to create a separate table and fill the data in it using procedure. There is still better way to do this(*using merge*). This is just for your reference.

```
create table daily_results
(`VISIT_DATE` date, `PAGE_ID` varchar(20),  `SERVER_NAME` varchar(50), `NUM_VISITS` int);

CREATE PROCEDURE proc_loop_test( IN startdate  date,  in enddate  date)
BEGIN

     WHILE(startdate < enddate) DO
        insert into daily_results (select * from PAGEVISITS where VISIT_DATE=startdate order by NUM_VISITS desc limit 5);
        SET startdate = date_add(startdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
     end WHILE;
END;
```

call it using

```
call proc_loop_test(`2015-01-01`,`2015-03-15`);
select * from daily_results;
```

Comment: This might not work on sqlfiddle. But it will surely work on mysql database.

Comment: Thank you very much Jigar. I extended the procedure to suit a few more scenarios.

Comment: You are welcome @usert4jju7 . It was nice question. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

The query should be

```
select sub.*,
        CASE WHEN @vd!=VISIT_DATE THEN @rn:=0 ELSE @rn:=@rn+1 END as row_num,
        @vd:=VISIT_DATE
from (
    select 
        VISIT_DATE,
        PAGE_ID,
        SUM(NUM_VISITS) as pagehits
     from
       PAGEVISITS
     where 
       VISIT_DATE >= '2015-01-01' and VISIT_DATE <= '2015-03-15'
     group by
       VISIT_DATE,
       PAGE_ID
     order by
        VISIT_DATE, pagehits desc) sub
having row_num<5
```

Somehow the SQL fiddle shows kind of internal error when the query is executed.

Comment: Thank you Stanislav. The `row_num<5` means there is no data returned at all. I don't know why though.